# Text fields in Python with tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to make my way through the documenation, but I'm having a hard time trying to find three specific things.

1. What is a text input.
2. How to get the text in a text input.
3. How to set the text on a text input.

Basically I would like to do as I just did in this example for javascript (it's really simple):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>SmallForm</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'temporal database', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE foo (id unique, field1 text, field2 text)');
    });
    saveData = function(){
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            var id = $('input[name=id]').val();
            var field1 = $('input[name=field1]').val();
            var field2 = $('input[name=field2]').val();
            tx.executeSql('insert or replace into foo values (?, ?, ?)', [id , field1, field2]);
        });
    };
    loadData = function(){
        db.transaction(function (tx) {
            var id = $('input[name=id]').val();
            tx.executeSql('select * from foo where id =?', [id],function (tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length;
                if (len != 1){
                    var text = len > 1? "bad data" : "no data";
                    $('input[name=field1]').val(text);
                    $('input[name=field2]').val(text);
                }
                else {
                    $('input[name=field1]').val(results.rows.item(0).field1);
                    $('input[name=field2]').val(results.rows.item(0).field2);
                }
            });
        });
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="line">ID:<input type="text" name="id" value="Introduce the ID first"><input type="button" onclick="loadData()" value="Load"></div>
    <div class="line">Field1:<input type="text" name="field1" value="some field"></div>
    <div class="line">Field2:<input type="text" name="field2" value="another field"></div>
    <div class="line"><input type="button" onclick="saveData()" value="Save"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I could not find this documentation for Python and I don't understand how the Tcl/Tk documentation maps to Python code. I guess I should check these:

- http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/contents.htm
- http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/contents.htm

But I understand nothing, either that is complex, I'm stupid or I skipped some important bits of information. Most probably it's a combination of all the former.

Thank you. Sorry if I did something wrong. All replies and feedback are welcome.

PD: I've been working on the code from @mmgp and I've produced this:

```
import sqlite3, tkinter as tk

def save_data():
  insertQuery = 'insert or replace into allData values(%s)'%(','.join(map(lambda x:'?',fields)))
  cursor.execute(insertQuery, tuple(map(lambda x: variables[x].get(), fields)))
  db.commit()

def load_data():
  cursor.execute('select * from allData where %s = ?'%fields[0], [variables[fields[0]].get()])
  row = cursor.fetchone()
  if row is None:
    for f in fields:
      variables[f].set("Bad data request")
    return
  for i in range(len(fields)):
    variables[fields[i]].set(row[i])


root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Fielder2013')
fields = ['id', 'field1', 'field2']
variables = {}
buttons = {'Load':load_data, 'Save':save_data}
dfields = {}

for i in range(len(fields)):
  e = fields[i]
  dfields[e] = (tk.Label(text=e), tk.Entry())
  dfields[e][0].grid(row=i, column=0)
  dfields[e][1].grid(row=i, column=1)
  variables[e] = tk.StringVar()
  dfields[e][1]["textvariable"] = variables[e]
i = 0
for e in buttons:
  c = buttons[e]
  buttons[e] = tk.Button(text=e)
  buttons[e]['command'] = c
  buttons[e].grid(row = i, column=2)
  i+=1

with sqlite3.connect('database.sqlite3') as db:
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute('create table if not exists allData (%s text unique%s)'%(
                 fields[0], ''.join(map(lambda e: ', %s text'%e, fields[1:]))))
  root.mainloop()
  db.commit()
```

The code may not be the clearest code you have ever seen but my little brain was trying to grasp some new concepts. I think it may be helpful for someone though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation can always be found at http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html. Also, searching for terms like "python tkinter" will return a lot of other places with useful documentation.

Following is an example that does nearly nothing, but replicates your code without calling into some database.

```
import Tkinter

def save_data(form):
    for widget in form:
        print widget.get()

def load_data(id_value, form):
    for i, widget in enumerate(form):
        widget.delete(0, 'end')
        widget.insert(0, id_value * (i + 2))

root = Tkinter.Tk()

lbl_id = Tkinter.Label(text=u'ID')
entry_id = Tkinter.Entry()
entry_load = Tkinter.Button(text=u'Load')
lbl_field1 = Tkinter.Label(text=u'Field 1')
entry_field1 = Tkinter.Entry()
entry_save = Tkinter.Button(text=u'Save')

lbl_id.grid(row=0, column=0)
entry_id.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_load.grid(row=0, column=2)
lbl_field1.grid(row=1, column=0)
entry_field1.grid(row=1, column=1)
entry_save.grid(row=2, column=2)

form = [entry_field1]
entry_load['command'] = lambda: load_data(entry_id.get(), form)
entry_save['command'] = lambda: save_data(form)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that's exactly what I needed to get through the initial steps in the learning curve, now everything makes sense, or at least many things. I've worked on your code and made a new version that I'm adding now to the initial post. Thank you again.